# Optimizing Permutation Search in File

Tags: python, file, search, optimization, permutation

I wrote a program that, using a set of characters, searches in a file for any of the permutations of that set. I would love your suggestions for optimizing that program.

I split the file into multiple, depending on the number of characters of each "word":

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import itertools
import time

start_time = time.time()
chrset = sys.argv[1]
lgr = len(chrset)
f = open('gd'+str(lgr), 'r')
perms = []
s = list(itertools.permutations(chrset))

for perm in s:
    perms.append(''.join(map(str,perm)))

for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    for pp in perms:
        if pp == line: 
            print (line)    

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: my idea maybe  ignore `\n` , use direct scan without line iteration. so `a =str(open('gd'+str(lgr), 'r'))`. but i am not tested ! if found you focus it.

Comment: @SDilmac I utilized your suggestion by reading the whole file and using split('\n'), it only decreased the runtime slightly, but thanks for the idea!!